# encoding, php, tinymce &check; check

Tags: php, encoding, tinymce

I have a question on encoding. I have a TinyMCE editor and when you put in the source code part `& check;`" into it is converts it to a check symbol when it saves into a `utf8_general_ci` database. When I pull it out into PHP code how can I convert that checkmark back into code that the browser will understand on a utf-8 page? I messed around with `htmlspecialchars_decode htmlentities html_entity_decode` but couldn't get any of those to work with the checkmark maybe I am using them the wrong way. Thanks for the help.

TinyMCE: 4.5.3 (using defaults)

**One Solution**

I found out my code files were not encoded as UTF-8 which didn't allow me to copy/paste the actual check symbol to find/replace it. I changed the php file to UTF8 and I was able to `str_replace` the checks with the html entity version. I feel like there's a better way but this works for now.

Comment: You've been around for *4 years and 10 months*, you should know adding a piece of code would would improve upon the question? Are you even connecting to your database using *utf8* encoding?

Comment: do you want to store a utf8 encoded check or `&check;` in the db?